# Yongnuo YN 160S - how to get inside?

Tags: hardware, lighting

My light has developed an intermittent power switch. I've never liked the pushbutton switch anyway, and would like to replace it, but I'm ashamed to admit that I can't figure out how to pry this thing apart without destroying it. Anyone ever done it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I'm an idiot, or was just really tired the first time I looked things over, because after taking another look today I realized that the shallow circular indentations at the corners of the face piece weren't molding marks, but screw channels with small, well-matched rubber plugs. I'll just leave this answer here for the next dummy... :D

[image: Rubber plug after digging it out with an x-acto blade]